# Tensorflow : RNN with char input

Tags: string, char, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I want to train an RNN on pseudo-random words (not part of any dictionary) so I can't use word2vec. How can I represent each char in the word using tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just doing characters you can just use a one hot vector of size 128 which can represent every ascii character (you may want to use smaller since I doubt you will use all ascii characters, maybe just 26 for every letter).  You don't really need to use anything like word vectors since the range of possibilities is small.

Actually when you use the one hot encodings you are kind of learning vectors for each character.  Say your first dense layer (or rnn layer) contains 100 neurons.  Then this would result in a 128x100 matrix multiply with the one hot encoding.  Since all but one of the values is non zero you are essentially selecting a single row of size 100 from the matrix which is a vector representation of that character.  Essentially that first matrix is just a list of the vectors which represent each character and your model will learn these vector representations.  Due to the sparseness of the one hot encodings it is often faster to just look up the row rather than carry out the full matrix multiply.  This is what the tf.nn.embedding_lookup or tf.gather function is used for.